# How to update loop counter to match number of Json("issues") on JIRA server?

Tags: json, excel, vba, for-loop, jira

I am writing VBA code to pull issues from my Jira server and populate Excel.

I have to manually enter the number of elements in the for-loop that there are (in this case there are three issues/ids on the website so "3" is the number in the for-loop).

If I switch 3 for 10 in the for-loop for example it throws

> "Run-time error '9' Subscript out of range"

How can I make the range match the number of issues/id in the webpage having to manually type the number?

I am using this JSON parser: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

```
Dim Json As Object
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response)

ActiveSheet.Cells(4) = "id"
For i = 1 To 3
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 4) = Json("issues")(i)("id")
Next i
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

`Json("issues")` is a Collection object, and that has a `Count` property:

```
Dim Json As Object
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response)

ActiveSheet.Cells(4) = "id"

For i = 1 To Json("issues").Count
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 4) = Json("issues")(i)("id")
Next i
```

Comment: `Json("issues") is a Collection object` - unless it's [a `Dictionary`](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas#L461).